# Symfony4 Route not found with path param if contains a dot

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

If I navigate to this route with this slug (/client/example.com)

```
/**
 * @Route("/client/{url}")
*/
```

I get this error

> The requested resource "/client/example.com" was not found on this
>   server.

I'm using php built-in server `php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 public/index.php`

With this aproach it works but assets doesn't load properly 
`php -S localhost:8000 public/index.php`

**Edit:**
without dot it works.

```
php bin/console router:match /client/example.com
[OK] Route "client_show" matches

php bin/console router:match /client/example
[OK] Route "client_show" matches
```

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/debug.html

Comment: Inbuilt server does not handle rewrites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Lawrence Cherone stated in the comments looks like it doesn't work with the built-in php server but it does work with the `composer require server` included in Symfony Recipes.

```
php bin/console server:run
```